# Why do triangles in multiple dimensions use pascals triangle

Tags: geometry, number-theory, solid-geometry, dimension-theory-analysis

If we take a triangle in 0 dimensions, and we count the number of points it has, we see it only has 1 (since anything in 0 dimensions is a point)
|Points|
|:----:|
|1|
If we take a triangle in 1 dimension, we get a line segment, which is made by a side, and 2 points
|Lines|Points|
|:---:|:----:|
| |1|
|1|2|
A triangle in 2 dimensions is a regular triangle, with 1 face, 3 lines, and 3 points.
|Faces|Lines|Points|
|:---:|:---:|:----:|
| | |1|
| |1|2|
|1|3|3|
In three dimensions, a tetrahedron there are 4 points, 6 lines, 4 faces, and 1 polyhedron
|Polyhedrons|Faces|Lines|Points|
|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|
| | | |1|
| | |1|2|
| |1|3|3|
|1|4|6|4|

This pattern coincides exactly with pascal's triangle (without the last '1' at the end of every row). Here, the pascal triangles row coincides with the dimension + 1, and the number in the row is for a certain property present in only some dimensions. Does this pattern continue in higher dimensions, and is there a reason for this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Elements

Comment: In each case you are selecting $k$ vertices of $n$ to make the different structures, which is a [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) and these are also formed in Pascal's triangle. There are questions and answers on MSE about this relation ([example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2834476))

Answer (score 1):

The underlying reason is that, increasing by one dimension, you add:

- 1 new vertex (dim =0);
- so many edges(dim =1) as previous vertices (dim =0);
- so many 2-facets as previous 1-elements;
  etc.